# Generic Decorator pattern using ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, mediatr

I am trying to wrap my generic interfaces with a decorator but it simply does not work, it seems to me from the other questions that the only way to do this is by explicitly doing it for each decorator, my question is about whether it is possible to wrap all types that implement a certain interface with a specific Decorater in ninject.

code:

```
 static void BindMediatr(IKernel kernel) {
  kernel.Components.Add < IBindingResolver, ContravariantBindingResolver > ();

  kernel.Bind(scan => scan.FromAssemblyContaining < IMediator > ()
   .SelectAllClasses()
   .BindDefaultInterface());

  kernel.Bind < SingleInstanceFactory > ().ToMethod(ctx => t => ctx.Kernel.Get(t));
  kernel.Bind < MultiInstanceFactory > ().ToMethod(ctx => t => ctx.Kernel.GetAll(t));
  kernel.Bind(
   x => x.FromThisAssembly()
   .SelectAllClasses()
   .InheritedFromAny(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler < , > ))
   .BindAllInterfaces());

  kernel.Bind(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler < , > ))
   .To(typeof(Decorater < , > ))
   .WhenInjectedInto < ApiController > ();
 }

 public class Decorater < TRequest, TResponse >
  : IAsyncRequestHandler < TRequest, TResponse >
  where TRequest: IAsyncRequest < TResponse > {
   IAsyncRequestHandler < TRequest,
   TResponse > _decoratee;

   public Decorater(IAsyncRequestHandler < TRequest, TResponse > decoratee) {
    _decoratee = decoratee;
   }

   public Task < TResponse > Handle(TRequest message) {
    // do something here
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this extension method which does the trick:

```
public static class KernelExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Binds an open generic type to its implementation and adds all its defined decorators
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">Ninject Container</param>
        /// <param name="openGenericType">Open generic Type</param>
        /// <param name="assembly">Assembly to scan for the open generic type implementation</param>
        /// <param name="decoratorTypes">Types of the decorators. Order matters. Order is from the most outer decorator to the inner decorator</param>
        public static void BindManyOpenGenericsWithDecorators(this IKernel kernel, Type openGenericType, Assembly assembly, params Type[] decoratorTypes)
        {
            var allImplementations = GetAllTypesImplementingOpenGenericType(openGenericType, assembly);

            foreach (var type in allImplementations.Where(type => !decoratorTypes.Contains(type)))
            {
                var genericInterface = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));

                // real implementation
                var parentType = decoratorTypes.Last();
                kernel.Bind(genericInterface).To(type)
                .WhenInjectedInto(parentType);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i <= decoratorTypes.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                var decoratorType = decoratorTypes[i];

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    // most outer decorator
                    kernel.Bind(openGenericType).To(decoratorType);
                }
                else
                {
                    // inner decorators
                    var parentType = decoratorTypes[i - 1];
                    kernel.Bind(openGenericType).To(decoratorType)
                        .WhenInjectedInto(parentType);
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesImplementingOpenGenericType(Type openGenericType, Assembly assembly)
        {
            return (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                    from interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces()
                    let baseType = type.BaseType
                    where
                    (baseType != null && baseType.IsGenericType &&
                    openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())) ||
                    (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
                    openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
                    select type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decorate the call for some method in all classes that realize the interface, you can try to proxy all your bindings.

Ninject has an extension called - [Interception](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Interception) which allows you to intercept the particular call to you method and wrap it by some logic.

[Here](https://baharestani.com/2013/12/30/interception-with-ninject/) is a good article about this.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: I need to be able to get the results of an Invoke Action which might be of a certain generic type Result<T> which interception does not seem to provide?